# how to convert PHP generated Feed to XML

Tags: php, xml

I've generated a Feed in xml-feed.php file using PHP SimpleXML, how can I "transfer" properly the output to XML file xml-feed.xml ?

```
  $xmlFeed = simplexml_load_file('https://feed_URL.com');
  echo "<products>";
  foreach ($xmlFeed->product as $prod) {
    echo "<product>";
    echo "<merchant_id>".$prod->merchant_id."</merchant_id>";
    echo "<upc_ean>".$prod->upc_ean."</upc_ean>";
    echo "<product_url>".$prod->product_url."</product_url>";
    echo "<image_url>".$prod->image_url."</image_url>";
    echo "<designation>".$prod->designation."</designation>";
    echo "<description>".$prod->description."</description>";
    echo "<brand>".$prod->brand."</brand>";
    echo "<category>".$prod->category."</category>";
    echo "<price>".convertCurrency($prod->price, "USD", "PLN")."</price>";
    echo "<availability>".$prod->availability."</availability>";
    echo "<condition>".$prod->condition."</condition>";
    echo "</product>";
  }
  echo "</products>";
```

Comment: you need to write to file  use fwrite or file_put_contents.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks! I'v made another approach :)
To xml-feed.xml on top I've added:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: application/xml');
echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>';
?>
```

and to .htaccess:

```
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php56 .xml
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$xmlFeed = simplexml_load_file('https://feed_URL.com');
$xml = "<products>\n";
foreach ($xmlFeed->product as $prod) {
    $xml.= "<product>\n";
        foreach($prod as $param => $param_val) {
            if($param!="price"){
                $xml.= "<$param>$param_val</$param>\n";
            }else{
                $xml.= "<$param>".convertCurrency($param_val, "USD", "PLN")."</$param>\n";
            }
        }
    $xml.= "</product>\n";
}
$xml.= "</products>\n";
//Writing to file
file_put_contents("xml-feed.xml", $xml)
```

All you need is to instead of echoing save them in a variable and after write them to a file.